# Multi-platform library to send commands on a remote server

Tags: c++, networking, remote-server, multiplatform

I have an application that currently runs locally on a PC and I would like to move some parts of this application on another PC. I would like the "remote" application to call certain functions when the "host" computer sends commands. The "remote" application would then communicate the information back to the "host" computer. Here is an example case:

- The host computer sends the "getIDList" command to the remote PC
- The remote PC sees this command and call it's local getIDList() function.
- The remote PC finds 5 id's, and send a message to the host computer telling it that 5 id's have been found, followed by the 5 id's.
- The host computer fills a table with the id's.

I would also like a human user to be able to send the same commands to the remote PC, which could be useful to debug "dynamically". That is, I'd like to be able to open a command prompt and send the "getIDList" command myself.

Is there a multi-platform library or API that would help me do this? I have no idea where to start, and I've tried searching but came up with absolutely nothing. This might be because I do not know enough about networking to even search using the correct keywords.

Comment: boost::asio, but you probably should look into Sockets, TCP, and UDP communication before you start down this road blind.

Answer (score 0):

try RPC. rpc is a library routines for remote procedure calls. These routines allow programs to make procedure calls on other machines across the network.